# what is the difference between stringstream clear and str

Tags: c++, stringstream

I just wanted to know what's the difference between clear() and str("");

For example:

```
stringstream ss("Stack Overflow");

ss.clear();

ss.str("");
```

I wanted to know the underlying technical difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`clear()` clears the error state flags in the `stringstream`. That is to say it sets the error state to `goodbit`(which is equal to zero).

`str("")` sets the associated string object to the empty string.

They actually do completely different things. The peculiar choice of names only make it *sound* as though they perform similar tasks.

Comment: I hardly think the naming is "peculiar" at all, they are not similar in the least. The fact that you think it is confusing perplexes me.

Answer (score 5):

```
void clear ( iostate state = goodbit ) //clears and sets error flag passed as parameter

string str ( ) const;          //to get value from string stream
void str ( const string & s ); //to set value to string stream
```

Comment: yesraaj does str( "" ) code also clears the flags in his inner code?